# Did Stack Overflow reset the review queue counter?

Tags: support, review-queues

I went to go do a few reviews for the first time in a long time this morning, and I noticed that all of my review queue counters are back at zero. Did I miss something? Did Stack Overflow reset the counters, or is this just a me thing?

[image: Low Quality Answers]
[image: First Questions]
[image: First Answers]
[image: Late Answers]
[image: Suggested Edits]
[image: Triage]

Comment: There are a couple of new queues but most of them are unchanged. Are you sure they are **all** zero or just the new ones?

Comment: Please read the [announcement of the review queue changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) over on Meta.SE.

Comment: You scared me there for a [moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M30ba.png) :)

Comment: Specifically, there is a proposal to port First Post credit: [Proposal for awarding credit towards First Questions/Answers badges based on First Posts activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369396)

Comment: Those counters are **daily review** counters, not your badge progress counters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ha, so it is. Well, that cuts my anxiety down. I seem to remember it used to show the total counter during reviews, so it freaked me out. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to know your total, press the [Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHrm6.png) links :)

Comment: If the queues were to be empty at any point, that would mean that the site is designed correctly. If they are never empty, then that means that the ratio between events causing reviews and people willing to do unpaid review work is broken. The latter also means that the queues will just keep growing. This is basic computer science: if there isn't enough processing power, then no amount of queues will save the program from eventually crashing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, review queue progress was not reset. First of all, you posted screenshots with *daily progress* trackers, showing you how many reviews you made *today*, those say nothing about your progress towards earning badges.

But, perhaps you are worried about your progress in the *First Posts* queue, which was retired as part of the [recent review queue changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release). That queue has been replaced by the new [*First Questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions) and [*First Answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) queues, and everyone started at 0 for those queues.

However, there are plans to [transfer progress to the new *First* queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369396/proposal-for-awarding-credit-towards-first-questions-answers-badges-based-on-fir). The work for that is not yet complete.